# Why I can't switch pages by navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do is switch between my pages by using BottomAppBar in my app but it doesn't work. what make it worse is that it doesn't show me any error so I don't know where is the problem.
Thank you for your help :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing/SecondPage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'MyApp',
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Icon(Icons.rice_bowl,size:100,color: Colors.blue,),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              hoverElevation: 50,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Icon(Icons.mic),
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
            FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
              //color: Colors.blue,
              notchMargin: 10,
              shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.contact_mail_outlined,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.local_activity,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  Container(
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => secondPage()));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.safety_check,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.read_more,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is second page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class secondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const secondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<secondPage> createState() => _secondPageState();
}

class _secondPageState extends State<secondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Icon(Icons.rice_bowl,size: 200,),
    );
  }
}
```

I did everything I found in flutter docs but still doesn't work.

Comment: I _am_ able to switch a new page - second page. However, I _can't_ go back, is that what you want? to be able to go back?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to navigate to a *new* page. However, I am not able to go back (pop) to the previous page.

Since you're pushing a *completely* new page, you should use a `Scaffold()` with an `AppBar` which will provide you with an option to go back to the previous screen.

You're `secondPage` Widget should look like this:

```
class secondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const secondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<secondPage> createState() => _secondPageState();
}

class _secondPageState extends State<secondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("second page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```